# Change Aquaris phone ringtone

Tags: ubuntu-touch, phone, personalization, aquaris

I tried adding more ringtones by following instructions here and on other fora, but when I typed: `sudo mount -o remount,rw /` in the terminal, I got the following message: `only root can usr "- - options" option`

I have already saved the audio files in .ogg format (in my downloads folder on the phone), but moving them to the ringtones folder is proving to be an impossible feat. Why is it so complicated, when this should be a straight-forward task?

I used to use Zedge on Android and change ringtones just by pressing a button. Is there a reason why the Aquaris phone has to make a simple task seem so complex?

Comment: You can change the ring tone in the settings of the phone without chaning the r/w status of your root partition.

Answer (score 1):

You have missed a space in the command. It should be:

```
sudo mount -o remount, rw /
```

instead of

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw /
```

If this doesn't help, please provide a full list of the commands (and their respective output) you're using.

Comment: Thanks. I used the extra spacein the terminal and tried to copy the files and paste them in the ringtones folder usingthe file manager. However, nothing happened.

Comment: For some reason the file manager still sees the filesystem as read-only and the only way I managed to do it was by copying from the terminal - "sudo cp ~/Music/ringtone.ogg /usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/ringtones/" (without the quotes). Of course you have to change ~/Music/ringtone.ogg to the actual filename of your ringtone. If you want to add new SMS notifications you have to change ringtones from the command above to notifications

Comment: Ok thanks Sledge Hammer. Once I copy the files from terminal ("sudo cp ~/Music/ringtone.ogg /usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/ringtones/") how do I paste them in the desired folder, then?

Comment: That's what the cp command does - it generally takes two parameters - source and destination and duplicates the content of source to the destination (so you don't need a paste command). In this case ~/Music/ringtone.ogg is the source and /usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/ringtones/ is the destination. In other words after you execute this command you should be able to see your new ringtone in System settings->Sound->Ringtone (might need to close and reopen the settings app). If you get an error make sure that you have provided the right source path for the ringtone.

Comment: Aaargh! I did the following: sudo mount -o remount, rw /      Then I typed sudo cp ~/Music/phone.ogg /usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/ringtones/   and I got the following error        cp: missing destination file operand after ' /home/phablet/Music/phone.ogg /usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/ringtones'

Comment: WOOHOO. It worked!! I realised that I didn't do a space between the ringtone and the rest :) Thanks a million

Comment: Great, I'm glad it worked.

Answer (score 1):

OTA-9 gives us finally the option to use custom ringtones with just some clicks rather than command line.
Simply go to Settings - Sound and choose under Ringtones for Custom Ringtone, which is placed in the end of the list. From there you get to choose your file manager (or another app) and go to the appropriate folder, where you have stored the piece of music, that you want to use as your new ringtone.